# Return zero for negative integers

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

A friend just throw some code similar to following C# code:

```
int i = ...;
return i < 0 ? 0 : i;
```

That made me think. There's any "different" way to return zero for negative integers, or current positive value? More specifically I'm looking for bitwise operations, if possible.

BTW, I'm aware of `Math.Max(0, i);`

Comment: How does this qualify as code golf?

Comment: i<0?0:i  --  Do you really expect something smaller than 7 characters?

Comment: Tell your friend not to throw code. It could hit someone in the eye.

Comment: +1 I won't throw code EVER again !!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What's wrong with `Math.Max`?

You *can* do the equivalent without a branch using bitwise operations:

```
r = x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); // == max(x, y)
```

If you substitute zero, it collapses to:

```
r = (y & -(0 < y)); // == max(0, y)
```

(Source: [this list](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax) of bitwise tricks.)

If branches were extremely expensive on your platform, that might be worthwhile in some inner loop, I suppose, but it's pretty obscure and not the kind of thing I'd like to come across outside of an *extremely* time-sensitive function.

Comment: Generally (x < y) is going to require a branch to convert it to either 0/1.

Comment: That's only true on some platforms.  Most have a compare instruction the result of which can be moved or shifted into a general purpose register.

Comment: @Aaron, Not true x86 is a **very** rich instruction set.

Comment: True - I just tried it and msdev used the 'setg' instruction -- so no branch necessary.

Comment: If MS's JIT is smart enough, Math.Max should already do just that.

Comment: While this kind of bit hackery is somewhat nice, it won't compile like this in c#, since the language doesn't allow arithmetic operations on booleans, so it would have to be r = (y & -(0 < y ? 1 : 0), which doesn't save all that much in the end

Comment: @Grizzly True that will generate a branch in CIL code.  For the `max(0,y)` case, though, you could replace the C expression `-(0 < y)` with the C# expression `-(int)(((uint)y >> (8 * sizeof(int) - 1)) ^ 1)`, which would generate 5 or so CIL instructions and no branches.  As if it wasn't ugly enough already...

Answer (score 6):

How about:

int i = ...;

return i & ~(i >> 31);

Comment: Good point - I modified it - it should now work for all cases.

Comment: Argh same strategy but much cleaner than mine. Didn't know the ~ to be honest

Answer (score 4):

The below will do the trick and the code reads so well it practically don't need a comment ;)

```
((((0x80000000 & i) >> 31)^1) * 0xFFFFFFFF) & i
```

then again

```
int temp = (0x80000000 & i); //get the most significant bit (1 for negative 0 for positive)
temp = (temp>>31)^1; //more it to the least significant and not it (we now have 0 for negative numbers and one for positive)

temp *= 0xFFFFFFFF; //get a lof of F's if it's positive or a lot of zeros if the number was negative

temp = temp & i; //and the F's/zeros with the original number
```

and voila zero for all negative number and all positive are left unchanged

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

Bit operators do something very different, or rather are used for different problems.

If you know the size of your integers, you could test the highest (most significant) bit; if it's 1, the number is negative and you can act on that. But that would be a heck of a lot more work than the simple "<" test.

Comment: And I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler already does this optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Not bitwise but different:

```
return (i + Math.abs(i))/2
```

EDIT:

```
return (int)(i/2f + Math.abs(i)/2f)
```

Comment: Kinky, but my overflow-sense is tickling :)