# can I do an assignment in C# with a shorter conditional statement

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there is simpler way to check a condition and assign the same variable if the condition is false similar to null-coalescing operator (??)

Here is how it can be done now

```
int i = 0;
...
int j = (i == 0) ? 1 : i;
```

Can it be made simpler like

```
int i = 0
...
int j = (i == 0) ?? 1;
```

I understand it won't work that way since ?? only checks for null. But I'm wondering if it can achieved with a different operator.

Comment: No operator will achieve this.  You can write a function, I guess.  Your before/after code isn't equivalent: `j` is never assigned `i` in the second code block.

Comment: You've got a solution that works perfectly and is 25 characters long.  You don't need a simpler solution, your solution is already *very* simple.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683029/return-zero-for-negative-integers

Comment: If I can have only positive values you could write `int j = Math.Max(1, i);`.

Comment: It is not similar since the other question is specifically looking for bit wise operators. I'm curious if C# offers a similar operator to null-coalescing that I didn't know for other conditions. I just chose integers for simplicity sake.

Comment: Servy, I can say the same about null-coalescing operator. Why use ?? when you can achieve same result with ?: with a null condition check.

Comment: null coalescing is simpler: `int? i = 0; int j = i ?? 1;`. But it only works for null, not any other value. So you have the simplest form already.

Comment: Will it always be 0 that you are checking for? And will 1 be the minimum value? If so, you can use `j = Math.Max(1, i);`.

Comment: Do you use the i and j in an loop,then you could initialize i with 1.

Answer (score 0):

**I think what you're looking for is impossible** in general (as opposed to when more info is available as I mention below). The reason is that you need 3 pieces of information for the job:

1. the value to check for
2. the value to use if true
3. the value to use if false

The `??` operator gets around that by assuming that `1` is `null`. But that would mean that you would need a separate operator for every value of `1` that you would want to test for. This is worthwhile for the C# team to write for something as common as `null`. Not for most things. (Of courses you could write your own for cases you know you need. But it seems like you're looking for something built in.)

**In your specific case**

Assuming that the minimum has to be 1, you can have:

```
j = Math.Max(1, i);
```

**In response to those asking why would the OP be looking** for simpler code than already very simple code, this might be to reflect the logic behind the action, and therefore be (in a sense) more readable.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed response. I'm specifically looking for a C# language feature similar to ?? and it looks like no such operator exists. I just chose int type as an example above. I should have used a string to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method for `int` types that will do what you want:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int IfZero (this int value, int defaultValue)
    {
        return value == 0 ? defaultValue : value;
    }

    public static int ReplaceValue(this int value, int valueToReplace, int replaceWith)
    {
        return value == valueToReplace ? replaceWith : value;
    }
}
```

Then it could be used throughout your program like:

```
int i = 0;

int j = i.IfZero(1);

// Or using the more generic method:
int j = i.ReplaceValue(0, 1);
```

Comment: Nice solution, but to be a little more DRY I would suggest having IfZero delegate to ReplaceValue

Answer (score 0):

No, the language does not offer that.

You can write a generic extension method, though:

```
public static class CoalescingExtensions
{
    public static T IfDefault<T> (this T value, T valueIfDefault)
    {
        return value.Equals(default(T)) ? valueIfDefault: value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code is using 0 to determine whether or not the variable has been initialized. However, this can create issues since 0 is a valid value for an integer.

If checking for a different default value is acceptable, try using nullable types. This will allow you to use the null coalescing operator.

```
int? i = null;
...
int j = i?? 1;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Comment: You're changing the starting value of `i` in order to make this work, though.  This won't work if `i = 0`, per the question.

Comment: But the OP wants `if (i == 0) j = 1; else j = i;`. This does not do that...

Comment: If `0` was used as default value, then changing this default value to `null` would allow the solution proposed here. Therefore this is a good, alternative solution. Because this might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Amy The 0 in the OP was being used to determined if the value was initialized. This can create issues down the road since 0 is a valid value for an integer. That's the reason I suggested this solution.